# Sorting a bound observable collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, observablecollection

I have an MVVM collection that I "know" is reordered in the VM but not showing in it's new order in the view. Given code similar to that below, should I expect the the list to re-display in a new sort without manipulating the CollectionViewSource?

## xaml

```
<Menu Name="_mainMenu" Height="22" >
    <MenuItem Header="Language" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableCultures}"  >
        <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <MenuItem IsCheckable="True" 
                          IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"  
                          Header="{Binding DisplayName}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

## vm

```
public ObservableCollection<OptionLocalizedViewModel<CultureInfo>> 
                                     AvailableCultures { get; private set; }

private void OnSelectionChange(OptionLocalizedViewModel<CultureInfo> option)
{
    ...
    var sorted = AvailableCultures.OrderBy(x => x.DisplayName);
    AvailableCultures = 
        new ObservableCollection<OptionLocalizedViewModel<CultureInfo>>(sorted);

    NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => AvailableCultures);
}
```

## UPDATE

The order *is* being changed, but not as expected (and not what the debugger shows the newly sorted ObsCollection to be). I also tried ditching the ObsCollection in favor of binding to an IEnumerable directly with the exact same result.

Does anyone see a pattern that suggests a fix??

## 1) initial load, looks as it should

[image]

## 2) select Spanish, so should be Espanol first but isn't

[image]

## 3) back to English, but somehow English is last. How did this get flipped?

[image]

## 4) back to Spanish, same as try (2)

[image]

Comment: Made a similar program and it worked for me, are you certain your NotifyOfPropertyChange is working correctly?

Comment: @KDiTraglia. No, and everything is suspect right now. I was even wondering if I needed INPC with an ObservableCollection that is being replaced, but as you can see it is in there.

Comment: It is needed since you are newing out and replacing the whole collection.

Comment: @KDiTraglia. well the bad news for me is I forgot that my test app view model was essentially hiding the "real" view model. the good news is that once I hooked into the real vm all works just peachy. You had the right answer the whole time - you don't need a collectionViewSource, you do need to fire INPC, and you do need to *check your INPC wiring* is correct. Please put that as an answer so I can give you proper credit and close this out. And thanks! Cheers

Comment: Glad I could help, I added an answer (though there wasn't much too it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should theoretically *work*, just be sure INotifyPropertyChanged is actually getting fired correctly as it is necessary when replacing the entire collection with a different one rather than just altering it's contents.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `ListCollectionView` instead :

```
 ListCollectionView LCV = new ListCollectionView(YourObservableCollection);
 LCV.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("PropertyName"));
 YourDataBoundProperty = LCV;
```

You can refer to [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/monikadyrda/archive/2009/08/31/wpf-listcollectionview-for-sorting-filtering-and-grouping.aspx) for more detail.

Comment: I didn't even know about this one. It is meant to wrap an observable collection?

Comment: @Berryl WPF uses ICollectionView internally when binding to collections. See CollectionViewSource (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.getdefaultview.aspx)